# question regarding for loop in combination

Tags: python-3.x

I have imported the permutation/combination from iter tools and when i loop over through that various combination of numbers the second for loop wont run again once it reaches the end. please see the code i guess it will make more sense

```
from itertools import permutations


def main():
list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
p2=permutations(list,2)
p3=permutations(list,3)

for a,b in p2:
   print(a,b)
   for c,d,e in p3:
      print(c,d,e)
```

the second for loop (for c,d,e in p3) will only loop over once and it will not loop over again

Comment: Please fix you indentation, as right now, your code won't run. Also, your question is not very clear. Please specify the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: I have fixed indentation. i am trying to print various permutations grouped with two numbers and another with three numbers. the second for loop is not looping after first run

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, because of the indentation the second for loop is run *within* the first run of the first loop. That is, the first loop runs `print(a,b)` then the second loop runs through the whole `p3` and only then the first loop is assumed again. I trust this is what you want, except that you'd like the second loop to run again over the whole `p3` once more for every iteration over `p2`.

The problem is that `permutations` returns an *[iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)* which, unlike *[iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)*, can only be run over once. Hence, the second time you try to loop over `p3` there's no more elements in it to return, the loop does in fact run, however there's no more `c,d,e` to be printed.

EDIT:

You can convert it to an iterable, simply by casting it as a `list`, for example by `p3=list(permutations(list,3))`.

Be careful though to change the name of your `list` variable which uses a reserved keyword and possibly use something more idiomatic like `lst = range(9)` or if you will `lst = [x for x in range(9)]`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. so is there any way i can loop it over over?

Comment: Yes, cast it as a list would be one. See the updated answer.